# How to conditionally set a C style string in C++?

Tags: c++, initialization, switch-statement

I am using C++ and do not want to use `std::string`.  I am trying to set the value of a C style string based on the value of a conditional.  Is this possible?

Here is a minimum working example:

```
#include <iostream>

void print_thing(int a)
{
    char* message;

    switch (a)
    {
    case 1:
        message = "case 1";
        break;
    default:
        message = "case 2";
        break;
    }

    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a{ 5 };
    print_thing(a);
}
```

This program is not in error but it seems bad form to set a non `const` `char*` to a string literal.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What if you do initialize the pointer? For example: `char* message = nullptr;`

Comment: If `a` is neither 1 or 2, what value does `message` gets? This is the exact error the compiler is complaining about. A `default` clause into the `switch` with an assignment there or an initialization in the declaration will get rid of the problem.

Comment: is it possible that it is a warning not an error?

Comment: @Alejandro thanks I updated the question. The error is gone but I do not setting a non `const` `char*` to a literal.

Comment: please dont fix code in the question according to comments/answers, doing so just makes the question less clear and may invalidate already given answers

Comment: "Is there a better way to do this?" simply use a `const char*`

Comment: @tobi303 word. I understand.

Comment: You are declaring a writable pointer to a writable character.  Text literals are read-only.  Declare your pointer as `char const *`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is fine, except that string literals in C++ are of type `const char[]` (unlike C where they are `char[]`). Therefore your variable must be declared as `const char* message;`.